# Assigning value to new objects made using constructors

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have just started writing JS for Google Apps Scripts to automate some of my Google Sheets. So my apologies in advance if there is an obvious error.

I have defined an object using constructor, when I try to make new objects of the same type giving the variable values in round brackets those values do seem to be taken.

Here's the code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("First Sorting");
var negsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Negative List");
function pastesheet (lastrow, append, pasterow) {
  this.lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  this.append = 1;
  this.pasterow = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
}
var neg = new pastesheet(negsheet.getLastRow(), 1, negsheet.getRange(1, 1));
```

From logger I observed that using the above code neg.lastrow actually refers to the last row of sheet "First Sorting" and not "Negative List" that I want it to refer to.
I also observed that the following tweak to the last line of above code does what I want:

```
ver neg = new pastesheet();
neg.lastrow = negsheet.getLastRow();
neg.append = 1;
neg.pastrow = negsheet.getRange(1,1)
```

However, I would really like to know what am I doing wrong in the first instance? It is quite convenient to assign everything in one line and I plan to do this for quite a few sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is referencing `sheet` which is not an argument and thus references the "First Sorting" `sheet` defined in the global body.

Did you intend to do something along these lines:

```
function pastesheet (sheet, append) {
  this.lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  this.append = append;
  this.pasterow = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
}
var neg = new pastesheet(negsheet, 1);
```

?

Comment: Thanks! My understanding of constructors was a bit off. I now understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: If this helped you please consider accepting my answer, thanks :)